# stata: sheet name not exist when saving

Tags: excel, stata

I'm writing a stata program accessing multiple sheets in an excel file, after my operation on them, I try to save the result, but it shows that the sheet name does not exist (**Cabo not found, r(111)**)
my code is like this:

```
clear
foreach sheet in "Cabo" "Ga" "Inha" {
import excel using "filename.xlsx", sheet("`sheet'") firstrow
//here are operations//
if `sheet' == "Cabo" {
    save test1018
    }
else {
    append using test1018.dta
    save test1018
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thank you!!

Comment: You need “” around both elements in the -if- statement. The loop fails when Stata thinks it is being told to look for a variable or scalar named -Cabo-. There is at least one other bug, the need for a -replace- option on the second and third -save-s.

Comment: Thank you Nick! I changed the code into --"sheet" == "Cabo"--, and added "replace" as you suggested. Now it returns the error --file Cabo not found-- r(601)..

Comment: You still need the single quotes as well, as in your -import- command.

Comment: … double quotes …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TheIceBear has pointed to good technique here.

The point of this answer is just that for three sheets a loop is not essential. This should work too, subject to details about files we cannot possibly check.

```
import excel using "filename.xlsx", sheet("Cabo") firstrow clear 
save test1018

import excel using "filename.xlsx", sheet("Ga") firstrow clear 
append using test1018
save test1018, replace 

import excel using "filename.xlsx", sheet("Inha") firstrow clear 
append using test1018 
save test1018, replace
```

I do agree that this is about as far as I would go without writing a loop, but the code is clear, transparent and likely to take you less time to write.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to include a `, replace` for when you save the data after the append. You can also simplify the code by starting by saving an empty data set before the loop. Then each sheet will be appended to this dataset and you do not have to treat the first sheet differently to the following sheets.

```
*Save an empty dataset to append to
clear
save test1018.dta, replace emptyok

foreach sheet in "Cabo" "Ga" "Inha" {
    import excel using "filename.xlsx", sheet("`sheet'") firstrow
    //here are operations//
    append using test1018.dta
    save test1018.dta, replace
}
```